# gnuplot: text label in gif terminal do not support font?

Tags: label, gnuplot, gif

In the following gnuplot code:

```
`set term gif
set output "try.gif"
set xrange [0:30]
set yrange [0:4]
set autoscale x
set palette model RGB
unset colorbox
unset xtics
unset ytics 
set object 1 rectangle from 3,3 to 28,3.5 fillcolor rgb "#0000FF" fillstyle solid 0.8 noborder
set label 1 "Stage1" at 15.5, 3.25 center  front font "arial,20" textcolor rgb "#000000" 
plot -1 notitle`<br/>
```

I want to draw a rectangle and place the text label over it. I hope I can control the size of the font. But when I insert `font "arial,20"` in my code, I get the following error message:
`gdImageStringFT: Could not find/open font while printing string Stage1 with font arial`

I want to make sure, it is because of my gnuplot tool or it goes just like that?

Comment: Because I only want to control the size of the font, so I tried `font ", 20"` and it works. That's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used term gif, but just out of curiosity: you DO have arial font and were using it in gnuplot before (under linux you can get it in msttcorefonts package)? Better to write it explicitly in your question :)